# jQuery heartbeat animation crashes

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

I'm trying to make a heartbeat animation with jQuery but it has some behavior I don't understand.

```
function pulse() {
    var target = $('body');

    target.animate({
        'font-size': '100.2%',
            'background-size': '230%'
    }, 200).delay(1600)
        .animate({
        'font-size': '100.1%',
            'background-size': '200%'
    }, 200, function () {
        window.setTimeout(pulse(), 4000);
    }).delay(200);
}
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jonathan_Ironman/wky7E/3/)**
It seems to me that the `setTimeout(pulse(), 4000);` is executed inmediatly, regardless of the timeout I use. Also, when I view it on my mobile phone it crashes after a short while.

I'm not too familiar with jQuery delay method but am I doing something wrong? I'm not sure if I read my own code correctly :)

**EDIT:

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jonathan_Ironman/wky7E/6/)**: It's my other code that crashes the mobile device 'click document to mute' code crashes it. Would you mind taking a glance at it and tell me if you see what might crash the phone?

Comment: “my mobile phone” — You might want to specify what you're using here; maybe it's just a bug in the browser you're using.

Comment: @coreyward Galaxy S2, might just be pushing it too hard I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setTimeout(pulse(), 4000);` should be `setTimeout(pulse, 4000);`

Notice there are no parentheses after `pulse`.

This is because when the parentheses are present, it means the function should be evaluated (which is what causes it's immediate execution). Without them, it is a reference to a function passed as an argument to `setTimeout` and will only be executed when `setTimeout` chooses to execute it, which is what you want.

Comment: Thanks, silly me. I removed the callback completely now and used `setInterval`. The interval still crashes the js when I view it on my phone though. Phone just can't handle timers?